# Microsoft Dynamics 365 Unified Interface - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, crm-ribbon-workbench

My D365 instance updated to Unified Interface and the JavaScript behind Ribbon Commands broke.
As I understand Xrm.Page needs to be replaced and PrimaryControl to be added as a Crm Parameter in ribbon workbench.

I did that, updated the code as well but I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getControl' of undefined
> at Object.OnSuccess
>
> at Object.ChangeStatusMultiple

This is the code:

```
Applikata.Commands =
{
    ChangeStatus: function (id, entityName, status, state, successCallback,context) {
        var formContext = context;
        var entity = {};
        var arrStatus = status.SourceControlId.split("|");
        var _status = (state == 0) ? 100000000 : 100000002;

        // status arraives in following form
        // ac_grade | NoRelationship | Form | ac.ac_grade.Button17.Button

        if (arrStatus.length == 4)
            _status = arrStatus[arrStatus.length - 1].split(".")[2];

        entity.statuscode = { Value: _status };
        entity.statecode = { Value: state };

        //console.log(status);
        // ac_grade|OneToMany|SubGridAssociated|ac.ac_grade.100000008.GridButton
        //console.log("ChangeStatus:" + id + " entityName:" + entityName + " status:" + status + " state:" + state);
        //console.log("SDK.REST:" + SDK.REST);

        SDK.REST.updateRecord(
            id,
            entity,
            entityName,
            successCallback,
            function (error) {
                alert(error.message);
            }
        );
    },
    ChangeStatusMultiple: function (selectedIds, entityName, status, state, gridName, context) {
        var formContext = context;

        selectedIds.forEach(
            function (id) {
                Applikata.Commands.ChangeStatus(id, entityName, status, state, function () {});
            }
        );
        Applikata.Commands.OnSuccess(gridName);
    },

    OnSuccess: function (gridName,context) {
         var formContext = context;

        console.log('Control ' + gridName);
        console.log('Name of grid' + formContext.getControl(gridName,primaryControl).getName());
       // Xrm.Page.getControl(gridName).getName().refresh();
        formContext.getControl(gridName,primaryControl).refresh();
        

    }
};
```

what am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expected to pass `context` as second parameter for the function `OnSuccess: function (gridName,context)`, you have to pass like this `Applikata.Commands.OnSuccess(gridName, formContext);` from calling place.

```
ChangeStatusMultiple: function (selectedIds, entityName, status, state, gridName, context) {
        var formContext = context;

        selectedIds.forEach(
            function (id) {
                Applikata.Commands.ChangeStatus(id, entityName, status, state, function () {});
            }
        );
        Applikata.Commands.OnSuccess(gridName, formContext);
    },

    OnSuccess: function (gridName, context) {
         var formContext = context;

        console.log('Control ' + gridName);
        console.log('Name of grid' + formContext.getControl(gridName,primaryControl).getName());
       // Xrm.Page.getControl(gridName).getName().refresh();
        formContext.getControl(gridName,primaryControl).refresh();
        

    }
```

Or you can set the formContext as global variable as well, instead of initializing it and passing in each function.

Comment: okay, did that and now I get this: formContext.getControl is not a function

Comment: @yiantheo can you debug by putting breakpoint and see the flow

Comment: I did that, everything is going fine until this line:console.log('Name of grid' + formContext.getControl(gridName,primaryControl).getName());

Comment: @yiantheo did you see what is coming in context variable?

Comment: Managed to get through this, and now I get formContext.getAttribute is not a function inside the form as soon as the form loads

Comment: @yiantheo that maybe coming from some other function

Comment: Indeed, coming from here: 'function InitSetup(primaryControl)
{
    debugger;
    var formContext = primaryControl;
    _isTest = false;
    _xrmTools = (_isTest) ? new XrmToolkit.Test([40, 20, 90, 40]) : new XrmToolkit.Common();
    formContext.getAttribute(Applikata.Grade.Fields.Exam(true)).addOnChange(CalculateResult);
    formContext.getAttribute(Applikata.Grade.Fields.CW(true)).addOnChange(CalculateResult);
    formContext.getAttribute(Applikata.Grade.Fields.Attend(true)).addOnChange(CalculateResult);
}'